# Cannot remap F2 in vim (vim.gtk)

Tags: key-bindings

I'm using this setting:

```
noremap <F2> :tabnext<CR>
inoremap <F2> :tabnext<CR>
```

But it just moves cursor down one line like `<C-j>` does...

How can I map F2 to moving to next tab?

Environment: Debian 9.5 amd64, KDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit - it was KDE + Gnome Terminator's fault (https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
noremap <F2> :tabnext<CR>
```

Should work from within normal mode. And it works for me. Check the output of `:verbose noremap <F2>`.

```
inoremap <F2> :tabnext<CR>
```

Will not work. You have to add `<ESC>`:

```
inoremap <F2> <ESC>:tabnext<CR>
```

That is because you will invoke it from insert mode and without escape it will just issue `:tabnext<CR>` as a text.

Comment: rather use `<c-o>` (or even better `<c-\><c-o>`) instead of `<esc>`. This has the advantage of staying in insert mode

Comment: Also prefer mode specific mapping command like `nnoremap` instead of `noremap` which maps the key in every modes even the ones where you don't need/want the mapping.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, generally I agree, but in this case I would go with `<ESC>` because of context switching (another tab) where I would like to be in normal mode.

Comment: @MaximKim good point, indeed!